# In-App Purchases show red bullets on Localizations languages in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, localization, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

[image]

I've entered several IAP items on App Store > Features with the newly submitted app.

The app is rejected and all of IAP items show red exclamation marks with 'Developer Action Needed' Status.

However, the red bullets of each localization say nothing about *why* they have red bullets. The three localizations are the same supported languages for the app along with three `Localizable.strings` files.

What can I do more on this page?

- I've already checked 'Cleared for Sale'.
- The red mark is shown regardless of Consumable or Auto-Renewable Subscription
- I've already added review screenshot and comments

Comment: Probably, it has nothing to do with your localizations. Last week there were someone with a similar problem. The solution was to fill the tax, agreements and billing section (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054122/1128713).

Comment: If you scroll to the top of the in-app purchase, do you have a yellow warning banner? We had a returned iap with the following message at the top: "Your in-app purchase has been returned. Fix the marked items and submit it again. For more information, see the Notes from App Review."

Comment: @Max no banner message was displayed for me. but the red bullets do not affect a submission itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea but this happens when I got a review rejection.

Below step is to mitigate the issue.

1. Just cut (for paste later) a description of an item.
2. Click Save.
3. Paste description to the item.
4. Click Save again.
5. Now the item turns to yellow.
6. Go outside to the list, now all IAP items shows yellow ('waiting for review' state).

It seems fine regardless of doing above steps before/after submit an app for review.

If we click one of yellowed items, we still have red bullets on other languages except what we did cut-and-paste. However, the reviewer seems not to care about them. They only care about the all-yellows states on the list, not inside item of the list.

When an app got approved to be released, the yellow items and their each included red-colored languages are all turned to green 'Approved' state.

Comment: .... incredible... what's Apple's market cap again?